# How do I fix "List index out range error"

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling

I am new to programming and right now I am learning about sorts so I was trying out the insertion sort and I don't know why the program is showing this error "List index out of range. Here's the code snippet.

[Screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15yL7.jpg)

Comment: Show some code.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
Include your code as a [formatted code block](//stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) instead of an image.

Comment: This error means you are trying to access an element that is not present in the list. For an example, if your list only has 3 elements, (indexes will be 0,1,2) and if you try to access the 4th element (`myList[3]`), you will get this error.

Answer (score 1):

So from your question what I can understand is that you are trying to traverse your list and sort it's elements, for that case you have to use `range()` and `len()` functions, so now it should look like:

```
for i in range(len(l)):
```

The `len()` function returns the length of the given object (list in your case).
The `range()` function returns a sequences of numbers starting from 0 till the given number.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [1,3,5,7,9,2,4,6,8]
```

element 0 = 1

element 1 = 3

....

element 4 = 9 ---> A[9] = out of range, trying to acces 9th element in the list, but the length of your list is 8.

if len(list) is the length of a list, and range(N) is the integers from 0 to N-1, then range(len(list)) is the integers from 0 to 1 less than the length of the list, i.e., all the legal indices of the list.

this should work:

```
A = [1,3,5,7,9,2,4,6,8]

for i in range(len(A)):
    j=i-1
    t=A[i]
    while j>=0 and t <A[j]:
        A[j+1] = A[j]
        j=j-1
    
    A[j+1]=t

print(A)
```

calling range() with one argument, gives a series of numbers that starts at 0 and includes every whole number up to, **but not including**, the number that user has provided as stop.
the range() function in python can take up to 3 arguments range(start,stop,step)
calling range with only one argument , only sets the stop.

for example:

```
x = range(9)
    for i in x:
print(x)
```

will print numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8